# Python Classes & inheritance

Tags: python, multiple-inheritance

I am learning and this is the class assignment, up until now we had only 1 class to deal with and I just cannot figure out the inheritance. I AM SURE there is an easier way to write this, but its what I can up with.

I need Batting_Stats to reach back to Baseball_Players and Team_Stats to reach both
Can someone help with the inheritance piece?

```
# Problem 1 (2 points)
# Assign the 'name' variable an object that is your name of type str.
name = "Baseball"

# Problem 2 (2 points)
# Create a class and implement it for your problem of interest
class Baseball_Players:
 def __init__(self, Fname: str, Lname: str, age: int, team: str):
        self.Fname = Fname
        self.Lname = Lname
        self.age = age
        self.team = team

 def fullname(self):
     return (self.Fname, self.Lname)

 def level(self):
     if self.age >= int(15):
         self.level = "Highschool"
     else: 
         self.age <+ int(14)
         self.level = "Not Highschool"
print("Player", Baseball_Players)

# Problem 3 (2 points)
# Create another class and implement it for your problem of interest
class Batting_Stats(Baseball_Players):
 def __init__(self, Plate_Appearances: int, Hits: int, Runs_Scored: int, Strike_Outs: int, Walks: int):
        self.Plate_Appearances = Plate_Appearances
        self.Hits = Hits
        self.Runs_Scored = Runs_Scored
        self.Strike_Outs = Strike_Outs
        self.Walks = Walks

 def Batting_avg(self):
      self.Batting_avg = Hits / Plate_Appearances

 def On_Base_Percentage(Batting_Stats):
     On_Base_Percentage = (Hits + Walks) / Plate_Appearances    

print("Average", Batting_avg)
print("OB %", On_Base_Percentage)

# Problem 4 (2 points)
# Create another class and implement it for your problem of interest
class Team_stats(Baseball_Players):
    

    def Hits_Per_Team(Batting_Stats,Baseball_Players):
        STLBEARS_H = Player1.Hits + Player3.Hits
        PACIFICHS_H = Player5.Hits + Player2.Hits
        FESTUSHS_H = Player4.Hits + Player6.Hits
        STLFORCE_H = Player7.Hits + Player8.Hits

    def Strikes_Per_Team(Batting_Stats):
        STLBEARS_S = Player1.Strike_Outs + Player3.Strike_Outs
        PACIFICHS_S = Player5.Strike_Outs + Player2.Strike_Outs
        FESTUSHS_S = Player4.Strike_Outs + Player6.Strike_Outs
        STLFORCE_S = Player7.Strike_Outs + Player8.Strike_Outs

print("Team Hits", Hits_Per_Team)
print("Strikes_Per_Team", Strikes_Per_Team)
# If you need to, you can create any additional classes or functions here as well.


Player1: Baseball_Players = Baseball_Players("Rocky", "Tucker", "11", "STL BEARS") 
Player1_B: Batting_Stats = Batting_Stats(10,6,2,1,1) 
Player2: Baseball_Players = Baseball_Players("Jaxton", "Harris", "15", "PACIFIC HS")
Player2_B: Batting_Stats = Batting_Stats(7,2,1,3,2)  
Player3: Baseball_Players = Baseball_Players("Donovan", "Emberton", "12", "STL BEARS")
Player3_B: Batting_Stats = Batting_Stats(12,7,5,3,2)  
Player4: Baseball_Players = Baseball_Players("Thomas", "Smith", "15", "FESTUS HS")
Player4_B: Batting_Stats = Batting_Stats(4,0,1,1,2) 
Player5: Baseball_Players = Baseball_Players("Wyatt", "Coleman", "14", "PACIFIC HS")
Player5_B: Batting_Stats = Batting_Stats(10,4,2,3,3) 
Player6: Baseball_Players = Baseball_Players("Jason", "James", "14", "FESTUS HS")
Player6_B: Batting_Stats = Batting_Stats(5,3,2,1,1)  
Player7: Baseball_Players = Baseball_Players("Ryan", "Renyolds", "13", "STL FORCE")
Player7_B: Batting_Stats = Batting_Stats(8,5,2,1,2) 
Player8: Baseball_Players = Baseball_Players("Johnny", "Depp", "12", "STL FORCE")
Player8_B: Batting_Stats = Batting_Stats(10,5,2,3,2)
```

Comment: The subclass `__init__()` method needs to accept all the parameters that the superclass does. And then it needs to call `super().__init__()` with those parameters in order to initialize the parent attributes.

Comment: Hello and welcome to StackOverflow!  Python supports multiple inheritance: `class Batting_Stats(Baseball_Players, TeamStats):`

Comment: `Team_Stats` shouldn't be a subclass of `Baseball_Players`. Subclasses represent IS-A relationships between types. A team's statistics is a collection of player statistics, it's not a type of player.

Comment: A batting statistic is not a kind of baseball players. Baseball players *have* statistics; `Baseball_Player` would just have an attribute of type `Batting_Stats`, rather than `Baseball_Stats` inheriting from `Baseball_Player`. You should probably talk with your instructor about when inheritance is appropriate.

Comment: As an aside, `15` is already an integer. You don't need to do `int(15)`.

Comment: Ok.. So in previous week we used a class as storage of information. 

so how I was looking at it. Baseball players is Primary. Player Stats is a listing of stats by baseball players with associated (super simple math). Team stats is a listing of team stats based on the player stats within. 

I added the super().__int__() and it at least resolved errors, but still no inheritance from one to another. 

Is it possible to connect Baseball Players (Player1, Player2, etc) to Batting_Stats(Player1_B) ?? Or am I really just looking/interperting the "guidance" I received wrong?

Comment: You are interpreting the guidance incorrectly. Reiterating what Barmar and I said previously, a baseball player *has* statistics; it is not a *kind* of statistic. Use inheritance to model IS-A relationships and composition to model HAS-A relationships.

Comment: Stack Overflow is not the place to get a custom explanation of basic OOP principles. You need to speak to your instructor.